# Finding a percent of $Y$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm looking for a multiplier to get a value of $Y$.

Calculation:

$Y+X=231272$ where $X=Y\times 15\%$  and $Y=231272 \times a\%$

I have tried all sorts of reverse calculation with no luck.

Comment: In narrow sense do you want to calculate y

Comment: Yes and the process in getting a multiplier to calculate Y

Comment: What do you mean by multiplier?

Comment: Y=231272∗**a**% - "a" is defined as a multiplier or a certain percentage. Once I know what "a" is, it's a simple calculation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick answer:
$$x + y = 231272$$
$$(.15y) + y = 231272$$
$$y = 201106.087$$
$$x = 30165.9$$
then, $$a = 87 \% $$
(note the arbitrary rounding)